# Modify x position of Gameobject while playing an animation - Unity

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

I have a gameobject with an animator controller. The gameobject moves from the bottom of the screen to the top, this movement is being controlled by the animation of th Y axis.

What i am trying to do is to also move it randomly in the X axis While the this animation is moving it in the Y axis

What i did was to set a few animation events in this main animation:

[image]

In this events i am calling a script that moves the object between 2 x positions:

```
public void RandomX ()
{
    var pos = transform.position;
    pos.x =  Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x, -1.75f, 2.85f);
    print(pos.x);
}
```

But this is not working. Tha animation plays with no modifications in the X axis.

Thanks in advance for any help provided

Comment: There is no modification of the `pos` variable, Math.Clamp(x, lowerBound, upperBound) only sets limits of the x coordinate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The animation overwrites the transform position. For your object to be controlled by code, you would have to change the hierarchy.

```
-object A with script controlling x position
     - object B with animation
```

Now you can move the parent object A by code. The animation controls only the object B.